# Specific Browsers are displaying whitespace at the bottom of phone screen

Tags: html, css, brave

I have a strange issue which occurs on specific browsers and is probably something to do with the viewport (I'm a new developer so do not fully understand the correct terms).

Browsers which have the issue:

- Brave Browser
- DuckDuckGo

Browsers which don't have the issue:

- Safari
- Google Chrome

When I scroll right down to the bottom of the page, there is a small amount of whitespace which does not go away regardless of what I do.

I have:

- Added width and height of 100% to footer
- Added a min-height of 100vh
- Checked for phantom characters
- Changed the position of scripts in HTML

Where the white begins is where the screen starts to curve (on an iPhone 11).

These are snippets of my CSS code which may be useful (the footer section is the second grey line to the bottom of the black section):

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
    font-family: "Raleway", serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Footer */
.footer {
    background-color: #0e1111;
}
.footer_wrapper {
    color: grey;
    max-width: 2000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 10%;
}
.copyright {
    font-size: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    border-top-width: 1.5px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-color: #232323;
}

/* End of code */
```

The bottom of my screen:
[image: My screen]

Does anybody know why this may be happening and if any more code needs providing, I will update the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the issue, I had to fill in the body colour.

```
body {
    background-color: black;
}
```

It seems to be something specific to individual browsers as many popular websites such as [bbc.co.uk](https://bbc.co.uk) and [news.sky.com](https://news.sky.com) to name a few, have the same issue (where the footer does not extend right to the bottom of the screen).